# To edit a row in Mui data grid by clicking edit icon on rows which make cells editable and the row should be selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am new to react and mui. I am trying to edit and delete files in data grid. I did bulk and single delete but not editing
[image]

As the design shown in image i uploaded few documents and listed it in data grid MUI. what i want is to edit a particular row while clicking edit button the document type and document remark should be editable. Document type are of dropdown list.

The expected output should be like this

[image]

```
    const columns = [
    {
      field: 'id',
      headerName: 'S.No.',
      filterable: false,
      width: 75,
      editable: false,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (params.id)
      } /* (index) => index.api.getRowIndex(index.row.id) + 1,*/
    },
    {
      field: 'path',
      headerName: 'Document Name',
      width: 150,
      editable: false,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (params.path)
      }
    },
    {
      field: 'doctype', width: 150,
      headerName: 'Document Type',
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (params.doctype)
      }
    },
    {
      field: 'remark', width: 140,
      headerName: 'Remark',
      renderCell: (params) => { return (params.remark) }
    },
    {
      field: 'edit',
      headerName: '',
      description: "Edit actions column.",
      sortable: false,
      width: 50,
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <>
            
            <IconButton aria-label="edit icon" sx={{ "&:hover": { backgroundColor: "transparent" }  
     }}
            >
              {(isEditable) ? <img id='editicon' alt="edit document" src={check_circle} onClick=
         {() => {
                setIsEditable(false);

              }} /> : <img id='editicon' alt="edit document" src={Edit1} onClick={(e) => 
          onEditClick(e, params.row)}
                 /* onClick={() => {
                  setIsEditable(true);
                  console.log(params)
                  let rowId = params.row.id
                  
                  console.log(rowId)
                  }} *//>}
            </IconButton>
          </>);
      }
    },
    {
      field: "deleteButton",
      description: "Delete actions column.",
      sortable: false,
      width: 80,
      renderHeader: () => (
        <IconButton aria-label="delete icon" sx={{"&:hover":{ backgroundColor:"transparent" }}}                
       onClick={() => {
        const selectedIDs = new Set(selectionModel);
          // you can call an API to delete the selected IDs
          // and get the latest results after the deletion
          // then call setRows() to update the data locally here

          let deletedfiles = selectedIDs.size
          setCounter(counter - deletedfiles)
          console.log(counter)
          setListoffiles((r) => r.filter((x) => !selectedIDs.has(x.id)));
        }}>
          <img id='deleteicon' alt="delete document" src={Delete_icon} ></img>
        </IconButton>
      ),
      renderCell: (params) => {
        return (
          <IconButton aria-label="delete icon" sx={{ "&:hover":{backgroundColor:"transparent"}  }}
            onClick={() => {
              const selectedIDs = new Set(selectionModel);
              // you can call an API to delete the selected IDs
              // and get the latest results after the deletion
              // then call setRows() to update the data locally here

              let deletedfiles = selectedIDs.size
              setCounter(counter - deletedfiles)
              console.log(counter)
              setListoffiles((r) => r.filter((x) => !selectedIDs.has(x.id)));
            }}>

            <img id='deleteicon' alt="delete document" src={Delete_icon} ></img>
          </IconButton>
        );
       }
      },
    ];
```

```
     <StyledDataGrid
                rows={rows}
                columns={columns}
                getRowId={(row) => row.id}

                components={{
                  NoRowsOverlay: () => (
                    <Stack height="100%" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" sx={{
                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                      fontStyle: 'normal',
                      fontWeight: 700,
                      fontSize: '18px',
                      lineHeight: '22px',
                      textAlign: 'center',
                      color: 'rgba(111, 125, 176, 0.5)'
                    }}>
                      No document uploaded
                    </Stack>
                  ),
                  NoResultsOverlay: () => (
                    <Stack height="100%" alignItems="center" justifyContent="center" sx={{
                      fontFamily: 'Lato',
                      fontStyle: 'normal',
                      fontWeight: 700,
                      fontSize: '18px',
                      lineHeight: '22px',
                      textAlign: 'center',
                      color: 'rgba(111, 125, 176, 0.5)'
                    }}>
                      Local filter returns no result
                    </Stack>
                  ),
                  LoadingOverlay: LinearProgress,

                  ColumnSortedDescendingIcon: ArrowDropDownIcon,
                  ColumnSortedAscendingIcon: ArrowDropUpIcon,
                }}
               
                // hideFooterPagination={true}
                //hideFooter={true}
                pageSize={5}
                rowsPerPageOptions={[5]}
                checkboxSelection
                disableSelectionOnClick
                onSelectionModelChange={(ids) => {
                  setSelectionModel(ids);
                }} />
```

Can someone who is familiar with react and datagrid  can solve this